# How to add decorator to class based view in django

Tags: django, python-decorators, django-class-based-views

I have signup class based view in my django authentication application. I created a new file:

*decorators.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def authenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect('/')

    return wrapper_func
```

and in my view I have:

```
from .decorators import authenticated_user
class Signup(View):
   @authenticated_user
   def get(request):
       ...
```

And it results in an error:

```
AttributeError at /accounts/signup-professor/
'ProfessorRegister' object has no attribute 'user'
```

But if I add same decorator to function based view it works. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: The same question has been answered earlier. You can refer to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41951132/19232446).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - How to use decorator in class-based view methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633259/django-how-to-use-decorator-in-class-based-view-methods)